# Only numbers are converted with code39 font in MsOffice

Tags: office365, code39

I've downloaded this code39 font:

https://www.dafont.com/code39.font

But when I use it in any MS365 Office product, only the numbers are converted, like below in Word:

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: The font doesn't contain lowercase letters. See the glyph map on dafonts

Comment: Ah how did I miss that! Moving to code128 :). Thanks Herr Strietzel.